# Can I convert an QuerySnapshot<Object?>? argument into an AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> argument?

Tags: flutter, dart, snapshot

I'm building an App on Flutter/Dart where posts can be made by the user. Each post is build through a "userpost" widget which takes the information from a firestore collection called "EventPosts" (using Streambuilder and a AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> argument). Each post is presented in the feed.

To get more details out of each post it's possible to click on one and a new screen, which is called "eventinfo" appears. This screen builds itself with information from the same AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> argument, due to "userpost" is calling "eventinfo".

On the same feed there is a search function which gets called after clicking the search button. The search function creates a searchSnapshot of the same firestore collection and returns it in the argument "searchSnapshot". Based off that searchSnapshot a Container is created for each search result. Meaning searching for a post, e.g. "soccer", every post with the name "soccer" appears.

What I want is that if one Container is clicked, the screen "eventinfo" shall appear with same layout as if it is clicked through a "userpost" from the feed. The screen "eventinfo" just accepts AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> argument. But the search function gives back a QuerySnapshot<Object?>? argument.

I tried several things. first of all I wanted to redirect from the search screen to eventinfo, by using InkWell with the onTap function:

`

```
onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context, ) => eventinfo(snap: searchSnapshot as AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>)));},`

//With the help of ChatGPT3 I tried to convert the searchSnapshot into a AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>, so I could call it like this:

onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context, ) => eventinfo(snap: convertSearchSnapshot (searchSnapshot))));},

//The convertSearchSnapshot had different approaches:

Future<AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>> convertSearchSnapshot(QuerySnapshot searchSnapshot) async {
    final snapshot = await AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>.withData(ConnectionState.done, searchSnapshot);
    return snapshot;
  }

  convertSearchSnapshot (QuerySnapshot<Object?> searchSnapshot) {
    final data = searchSnapshot.docs
      .map((doc) => doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)
      .toList();
    return AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>.withData(
      ConnectionState.done, QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>(data: data));
  }

  AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> convertSearchSnapshot (QuerySnapshot<Object?> searchSnapshot) {
    final data = searchSnapshot.docs.map<Map<String, dynamic>>((doc) => doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>).toList();
    final convertedQuerySnapshot = QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>(docs: [], size: data.length, metadata: searchSnapshot.metadata);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      convertedQuerySnapshot.docs.add(QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>(data: data[i], reference: searchSnapshot.docs[i].reference));
    }
    return AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>.withData(ConnectionState.done, convertedQuerySnapshot);
  }

  convertSearchSnapshot (QuerySnapshot searchSnapshot) {
  QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> querySnapshot = QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>.fromSnapshot(searchSnapshot);

  AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>
  AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> asyncSnapshot = AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>.withData(ConnectionState.done, querySnapshot);

  return asyncSnapshot;
  }

  convertSearchSnapshot (searchSnapshot) {
    QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> querySnapshot = QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(
    searchSnapshot.data()!.docs.map((doc) => doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>).toList(),
      );

      AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> asyncSnapshot = AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>.withData(ConnectionState.done, querySnapshot);
  }
```

I am assuming that due to several error messages this is not working..